# Parsing JSON Array without keys in NESTED PATH

Tags: json, oracle

I have a JSON like this (see the test setup below)

```
{
  "dt" :
  [
    {
      "values" :
      [
        {
          "key" : "a"
        },
        {
          "key" : "b"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and it is straightforeward to parse the inner array as it has keys as follows

```
SELECT tab.id, 
       jt.*
FROM parse_json_array tab,
       json_table(data, '$.dt[*]'
         COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$.values[*]' COLUMNS(
                     key     PATH '$.key'  ) 
    )) AS "JT"
where tab.id = 1;
```

which returns

```
ID, KEY
--------
1   a
1   b
```

But if the *inner* array has no keys, how could I addapt the path in `NESTED PATH`?

```
{
  "dt" :
  [
    {
      "values" :
      [
        "a",
        "b"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

All my try such as `key     PATH '$.*'` or `key     PATH '*'` return `null` or syntax error.

Note I *do not need* a solution, that parse both variants, but it would be of course a *bonus*;)

I'm on XE 18.4.0.0.0

**Test data**

```
create table parse_json_array
(id int primary key,
 data CLOB constraint c1 check(data is JSON)
 );

insert into parse_json_array (id, data) values (1, '{ "dt" : [ {"values" : [{"key" : "a"} , {"key" : "b" } ]} ] }'); 
insert into parse_json_array (id, data) values (2, '{ "dt" : [ {"values" : [  "a" ,   "b" ]}] }');
```

Comment: Please add the exact output you need from your input

Comment: Agree with mathguy, providing the expected result would make the question clearer. Having said that it appears you probably just want PATH '$'.

Comment: @Padders updated and `'$'` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the `id` and the values within the nested array, when it's just an array of scalars rather than objects.

```
SELECT tab.id, 
       jt.*
FROM parse_json_array tab,
       json_table(data, '$.dt[*].values[*]'
         COLUMNS  key     PATH '$'  ) 
     AS "JT"
where tab.id = 2;
```

Storing JSON in both formats, and even more so, asking for a solution that works for both, doesn't make a lot of sense; the JSON structure is different. It's like asking for a SQL SELECT query that works for two different tables with different column sets.

---

If you need a solution with nested path (perhaps because you must pick out additional bits of data, which you did not share with us), you can do something like this (which is what Padders suggested in a comment):

```
SELECT tab.id, 
       jt.*
FROM parse_json_array tab,
       json_table(data, '$.dt[*]' columns(
         nested path '$.values[*]'
         COLUMNS  (key     PATH '$'  )) )
     AS "JT"
where tab.id = 2;
```

EDIT:

To get values both from object members and from scalar members of the nested array, you can do something like this. Use `nvl(k_token, token)` if you just need the value and don't need to know if it comes from an array of objects or an array of scalars. Note that this solution will work even if you have objects and scalars mixed together in the **same** JSON (in the same nested array).

```
select p.id, j.k_token, j.token
from   parse_json_array p,
       json_table(data, '$.dt[*].values[*]'
           columns( k_token path '$.key',
                      token path '$'
                  )
       ) j
;
```

Comment: yep, `'$'` works, thanks, it seems to by something like *xpath* `text()`. "doesn't make a lot of sense" - it seems you work only in *lucky* projects

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - I don't work at all anymore (and never worked in IT in any capacity anyway); I understand what you mean, but "having to work on a project you can't control" doesn't mean it makes sense!

Comment: Understood. Despite the *sense* is a selection of the array `value` posible with one *path* in both cases with and without keys?  @padders pls comment as well.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - you can combine the two queries in one (two different columns in the `columns` clause - or combine them in one using `nvl`). See EDIT to my reply. Not pretty, but it will work. The more curious thing is that the value of `dt` is an array - in your example it contains a single object with key `values` and value a (nested) array - either of objects or of scalars. In real life, does the outer array (the value of `dt`) have other members, in addition to the object with key `values`? And if so, what do you need to extract from it?